# I don't know my Database name

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite

I am new to python-django.

I made a database in django and  I am able to call all the functions and use it properly. The problem is that I don't know if the database is in mySql or SQLite.

I ran sqlite and sqlite3 commands in terminal and it says that program is not installed. When I run MySQL commands, it is installed but doesn't show my database in `show databases` command.

I didn't know about the changes in `settings.py` file and directly jumped into `views.py` file.

I don't know my database name also. I am posting my `settings.py` file. Can anyone help please, I have to create dump of my database.

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ')mjm**********************************0b'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'law_app',
]
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'TheLawyerApp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'TheLawyerApp.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'` sqlite3 it seems... and btw, sqlite3 is preinstalled on macs

Comment: @HugoHonorem I am using ubuntu.. 14.04

Comment: You shouldn't post your config with the `SECURUTY_KEY` online! Now that you did, make sure to change it if your installation is actually online somewhere.

Comment: @mata Thank you so much!. I have updated my question.

Comment: @PrakharSrivastava - There's little point to that now, it's already been compromised. Make sure to change the security key in your application then it won't matter.

Comment: @mata okay.. can you tell me how can it  affect  my application if I don't change it?

Comment: It will invalidate any currently active cookie and therefore session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python comes with sqlite3 included, but if you only want to dump the data then:

```
django-admin dumpdata
```

or

```
python manage.py dumpdata
```

will do it for you. For more details read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata where it says:

> --output OUTPUT, -o OUTPUT
>
> New in Django 1.8.
>
> Specifies a file to write the serialized data to. By default, the data
>   goes to standard output.

which means that if you're using a Django version >= 1.8 you could use:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --output my-database-dump.json
```

and if you're on an earlier version of Django you would need to use:

```
python manage.py dumpdata > my-database-dump.json
```

Comment: I tried the second command in my project directory, it worked i guess, because it showed all the tables with details on terminal.. but once it is created, where can i find the dump?

Comment: Yes I read, it says "The output of dumpdata can be used as input for loaddata", but doesn't tell where is the dump.